# Delphi Mysql Stored Procedure Single Quote Trouble

Tags: mysql, delphi, stored-procedures

I have Delphi application with mydac stored procedure component which takes an utf8 encoded xml file's content as string parameter. 
It works with navicat and other db managment programs when I put this xml content copy-paste from file to procedure like

```
CALL sp_saveit('<xml>garry&#39;s<otherdata> data data....</xml>);
```

But when I try to call it from delphi it throws error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL sp_saveit('<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding="UTF-8"?><Main><Detail z') at line 1
```

*Am following those steps:*

1. delphi finds and reads file contents into a TStringStream with LoadfromFile `MyStream.LoadFromFile(Sp_xmlfile);`
2. then am passing contents to stored procedure `T_ContentsSP.ParamByName('XmlFile').AsWideString := MyStream.DataString;`

Also I've tried to compress this data with delphi's zlib and send as blob, I've tried to change `&#39;` with ' but result was same.

How can I send a long string with single and double quotes inside as parameter for sp with delphi?

p.s : sorry for my english.

Comment: Q: Why not just use the Delphi "StringReplace()" function to change all "'" to "''"?  EXAMPLE "`it's easy to embed quotes`" => "`it''s easy to embed quotes`".

Comment: QuotedStr() function (built-in in Delphi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post, I see that you tried to use a constant value (`I put this xml content copy-paste`) and a parameter (`T_ContentsSP.ParamByName('XmlFile')`). Also, try to show error text for the command you are used, and not for a different command.

When you are using parameters you does not need to do any special preparation. Data access components have transparently send parameter values to a DBMS. If they have tracing output, then check the trace, what library is sending to a DBMS. Parameter usage is always prefered agains literal usage !

When you are using a constant, then you should ([more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)):

- double each single quote inside of the constant and prepend it by '\'. So, a `'` will become `\''`.
- double quotes rather not need a special handling.
- probably disable macros handling, because '&' may be a macro specifier in the data access library.